# Change #hash tag to link on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, tags

How to change # tag + Character to link using javascript

```
This is going #right on the way
```

with

```
This is going <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search/right">right</a> on the way
```

even this is also acceptable

```
This is going <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search/right">#right</a> on the way
```

The page lots's of # (hash) tag in different classes and id's

Comment: If you can do it server-side, please do. (i.e. w/ PHP)

Comment: @kelly is there any way to do this with javascript..!!

Comment: This Q is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275650/javascript-replace-command-replace-page-text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var string = "This is going #right on the way";
string.replace(/#(\S*)/g,'<a href="http://twitter.com/#!/search/$1">$1</a>')
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dKm82/

Comment: I removed my comment after seeing your demo..!! at first i got confused
sorry for that..!!

Comment: @Basic Bridge got it, no problem

Comment: here is one little problem it multiply text 2 times..
see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/dKm82/1/

Comment: the problem has to do with the jquery logic, if you want to modify the text of several paragraphs you have to loop over them, see http://jsfiddle.net/dKm82/2/

Comment: and this is last query what if condition is like this one http://jsfiddle.net/dKm82/3/ this only change first letter not all in the <p> tag

Comment: @BasicBridge you have a point there, there was a little detail, note that i added "g" to the regular expression, this tells it to repalce multiple times see: http://jsfiddle.net/dKm82/4/

Answer (score 1):

here is my suggestion

```
(function(){

$.fn.hashlink = function(){
  this.text(this.text().replace(\#(w+)\),"<a href='twitter.com/#!/search/$1'>$1</a>")
  text = \#w+\g.
}    

})
```