# RegEx issue with hash tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html

I am trying to match hash tags and wrap them with an anchor tag. 
Here is the POC:

```
<p class="display"></p>
```

```js
var content = "I like #redApple. I have a #black hat. #red is my favorite color";

var re = /(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*)/ig,
    match, matches = [];

while (match = re.exec(content)) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}

for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    value = matches[i];
    console.log(value + ".....value");
    vSearch = value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.=()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
    console.log(vSearch + ".......vSearch");
    regExSearch = new RegExp(vSearch, 'g');
    console.log(regExSearch + "........regExSearch");
    content = content.replace(regExSearch, '<a href="#">' + value + '</a> ');
}

$(".display").append(content);
```

```css
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I am facing a problem: if the last hash tag word is matching any other word's first characters then its wrapping only that part of the word. For this POC, "red" is the last hash tag, that's why first "redApple" becomes "red" only. It should wrap the whole word "redApple".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Found a better regex here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13655378/3639582. You can try it.

Comment: Try with `'ig'` instead of `'g'` when instantiating `vSearch`.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I tried this. Its not not working as I expect. Its removing other words except "red" :(

Comment: Thanks sp00m..tried with ig, but not working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final answer

It appeared that the hashtag regex did not support Unicode letters. Since `\p{L}` is not universally adopted in all JavaScript environments, I suggest using the character class that will replace it (taken from [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/src/addons/unicode/unicode-categories.js)). The `\b` word boundary would not work with them as they are not treated as word characters, and thus, we need a `(?![^<]*</a>)` look-ahead that will check if the hashtag is already enclosed in `<a>` tag.

The code looks like:

```js
var content = "I like #red-Apple. I have a #black_hat. #red is my favorite color. #speçial. #anötherSpecial #estã, and #ãest. But also remember about #pisklę! Was it #Świętą?! #русский тест.";
var re = /#(?![-_])[-_0-9A-Za-z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B2\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA7AD\uA7B0\uA7B1\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9EF\uA9FA-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB5F\uAB64\uAB65\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]+(?![^<]*<\/a>)/ig;
content = content.replace(re, '<a href="#">$&</a>');
$(".display").append(content);
```

```css
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="display"></p>
```

Here is a modern JavaScript solution based on the ECMAScript 2018+ standard that supports Unicode character (property) classes:

```js
const content = "I like #red-Apple. I have a #black_hat. #red is my favorite color. #speçial. #anötherSpecial #estã, and #ãest. But also remember about #pisklę! Was it #Świętą?! #русский тест.";
const re = /#(?![-_])[-_\p{L}0-9]+(?![^<]*<\/a>)/gui;
$(".display").append( content.replace(re, '<a href="#">$&</a>') );
```

```css
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="display"></p>
```

## Original answer

You can use a combination of a [non-word boundary and a word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
regExSearch = new RegExp("\\B" + vSearch + "\\b", 'g');
```

Here, `\B` will match at the non-word position (between word characters, or non-word characters, and `\b` will match at other positions (between a word and non-word character).

Also, I removed the 2 lines below in your code that are redundant:

```
vSearch = value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.=()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
console.log(vSearch + ".......vSearch");
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that you are using a capturing group around the whole regex pattern `(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*)` and then creating an array "manually". You do not need it in fact, and can easily get an array with `match` using `#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*`.

The code that is working:

```js
var content = "I like #redApple. I have a #black hat. #red is my favorite color";

var re = /#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*/ig;
var matches = content.match(re);

for (i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    value = matches[i];
    console.log(value + ".....value");
    regExSearch = new RegExp("\\B" + matches[i] + "\\b", 'g');
    console.log(regExSearch + "........regExSearch");
    content = content.replace(regExSearch, '<a href="#">' + value + '</a> ');
}

$(".display").append(content);
```

```css
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="display"></p>
```

HTML obtained:

[image]

Comment: Thanks stribizhev, I tried this. I am getting correct hash tags but its not wrapping with <a> tag.

Comment: I attached an image that shows `<a>` tags are added. Also, Smileek is right saying there is no point in escaping regex special characters, they won't occur since you use `#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*`  regex to obtain the list of hashtags.

Comment: Great it worked, please consider also upvoting if you found the answer useful. I reduced the code a bit by using the `string.match(pattern)`.

Comment: Sure stribizhev...I have a new problem. If there is any special character inside hash tag then its separating from there. It should take whole word with special character. Do u have any suggestion for this? http://jsfiddle.net/pw5e05dy/8/

Comment: This makes it a bit different question. The hashtag regex depends on the hashtag syntax. Do you know exact requirements?

Comment: Yah, the requirement is if there is any non english character anywhere in hash tag, that should also treat as whole word. like #speçial. <a> sld wrap the complete word. not only just before the non english character. I have done this but if the character is at end then its not taking. Any idea? http://jsfiddle.net/pw5e05dy/10/

Comment: Try `\B#\S+(?=[,?.!:;])`. This means you will also have to revert the 2 lines of code that escaped the hashtag. There are other caveats when hashtags that may contain non alphanumeric characters. Perhaps, you will have to sort the hashtag array by string length so that the longest are replaced first.

Comment: can u pls give me a fiddle link? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that if the extended letter is at the end we cannot use `\b`. I am on the mobile, I won't be able to help much now. If you could use XRegExp library you could support unicode in js easily.

Comment: Ahh ok...Thanks for your efforts...appreciated

Comment: I am not using XRegExp. I am still struggling with this. We have done till this jsfiddle.net/pw5e05dy/14 only thing is left now is if there is any non english character at 1st or last position then those words are not wrapping with <a> tag. for this case u can see the words #estã #ãest are not wrapped with <a> tag. If you can update in fiddle link when u get some time, tht will so helpful for me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Bryce77: Please have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/am1o10u0/1/). I have made use of the `\p{L}` Unicode category taken from the [XRegExp library](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp/blob/master/src/addons/unicode/unicode-categories.js).

Comment: Thanks stribizhev..but we are getting the old issue here. 1st word is separated #redApple :(

Comment: Ok, I think this can be fixed with a look-ahead `(?![^<]*</a>)` that is checking if there is no optional text and a closing `</a>` tag. See [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/am1o10u0/2/).

Comment: Hi stribizhev, I am facing a small problem here. at the end #abcsports is not covering with <a> tag..can u pls help?... http://jsfiddle.net/am1o10u0/4/

Comment: I felt we need to sort the matches first... [Here is the update](http://jsfiddle.net/am1o10u0/5/).

Answer (score 0):

hi your Problem might solve by using strict check by creating with RegEx by using **' $ '**

```js
var re = /(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*)$/ig,
```

use this RegEx this may will Work.

Comment: Thanks Himesh...tried this..its taking the correct hash tags but not wrapping with anchor..

Comment: Hey i can't getting it >? " anchor "...? can you explain then only i can help you

Comment: we have done till this http://jsfiddle.net/pw5e05dy/14/                                      only thing is left now is if there is any non english character at 1st or last position then those words are not wrapping with <a> tag. for this case u can see the words #estã #ãest are not wrapped with <a> tag. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it this way (it's much simpler, actually):

```
var content = "I like #redApple. I have a #black hat. #red is my favorite color";

var re = /(#[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-_]*)/ig;

content = content.replace(re, function(x) { return '<a href="#">' + x + '</a> '; });

$(".display").append(content);
```

`vSearch = value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.=()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');` in your code is redundant - you don't need it since your matches won't have any of these symbols according to regexp you used to get them.