# validation using \p{L} in JavaScript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

```
**var pattern = /^[\p{L}0-9 @#'!&(),\[\].+/-]{1,100}$/;** \\first of all I din understand this pattern. someone plz explain it to me\\
if (!pattern.test(Name)) 
        {
            alert('Account Name must not contain the given values');
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("name").setValue("");      
            return false;
             } 
        else
        {       
            return true;
        }
```

when I give this as validation it is throwing error message for all the values I enter. So I need some explanation on the pattern which I think will solve the rest.

Comment: Please check [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31115742/3832970), there is `$re` pattern where you can remove the first `#` and `0-9A-Za-z` in the character class to match all Unicode letters but astral code points.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript, the sequence `\p{L}` (in a character class) has no special meaning; it simply means the letter `p` or the letter `{` or the character `L` or the character `}`. You're probably getting confused with [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode), another library, or another language's (eg [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html), PHP, .NET etc.) implementation of regexps, which support so-called Unicode character categories.

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
/^[\p{L}0-9 @#'!&(),\[\].+/-]{1,100}$/
```

to

```
/^[\p{L}0-9 @#'!&(),\[\].+\/-]{1,100}$/

                          ^^
```

since you have to escape slashes `/` since you have defined them to be delimiters.

The meaning of the regex is that your entire string has to be between 1 and 100 characters of the listed characters, numbers and letters.

Comment: Is p{L} and [a-zA-z] are same?
I read that p{L} is  a Unicode and java doesn't accept Unicode. If both are same then shall I replace

Comment: Actually, you **do not** need to escape the forward slash when it is part of a character class. So that's not the OP's problem.

Comment: I assume you mean javascript and not java. p{L} means some form of "letter". Only if you have only ASCII characters is it the same as [a-zA-Z].

Comment: It is not possible to use `\p{L}` in JavaScript (at least now).