# Regex jquery validate keeps failing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a input field with jquery and the validate plugin. But my regex keeps failing. The regex works perfectly if I use ajax and run it through a php file. But I dont want to run a ajax request for every character thats written in the input field. Do regex behave diffrently in javascript? Do I have to place the flag another place?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\p{L}[\p{L}
>   \'&-]*[\p{L}]$/: Invalid escape

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "regex",
  function(value, element, regexp) {
    var re = new RegExp(regexp);
    return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
  },
);

contact_name: {
  required: true,
  regex: /^\p{L}[\p{L} \'&-]*[\p{L}]$/u
}
```

Comment: "Do regex behave diffrently in javascript?" Yes, you will have to write js variant for this regex, because js regex engine doesn't recognize special chars you have used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450128/validation-using-pl-in-javascript-regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has a different kind of regex. You can verify your expression [here](https://regexr.com/). It is a nice web.

I think that you are trying to do this:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z '&-]*[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: Thanks! ok ill have to do some rewriting of my regex then