# regex for hashtags

Tags: regex

I have found a lot of regex examples to retrieve hashtags from a text. Unfortunately, none of examples is what I need.

This is almost what I need but...

```
function hashtags(text) {
return text.replace(/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w{2,50})/g, 
"$1<a href='/h/$2' target='_blank'>#$2</a>");
}
```

Hashtags can not start with a number to avoid situations when for example **Section #12** gets hashtaged.

The example above checks it but it does not allow characters like ÁÉÍÚ, it does not check the hashtag lenghth correctly and it does not allow character '-'.

**So, I need the following:**

1. A hashtag may start with any letter - A,z,B,Ñ,ó,Ú etc, but not with a number and not with a special sign &%$ or - _
2. The total lenght of a hashtag must be 3-50 characters. The regex must accept as hashtags only full words but not to cut them after first 50 characters. So, words that start with # but contain more than 50 characters must be ignored instead of converting first 50 characters into a hashtag link. In my example `{2,50}` does not work correct.
3. The rest part of a hashtag (when checked that it does not start with a number or a special sign) may contain numbers, any letters and `_ -` signs. `\w` allows only `_` but not `-`

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you a simple input for testing?

Comment: I think you can adapt [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31115742/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/(^|\s)#([^\d&%$_-]\S{2,49})\b/g
```

Explaining:

```
(^|\s)           #
#([^\d&%$_-]     # not the characters you mentioned in the first position
\S{2,49})        # the first chracter was already matched
\b               # a boundary to avoid overflow 50 characters
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For 1 - you need a character class. You can define these with square brackets. PCRE defines `\w` but that includes numbers too.

For 2 - You can either have a word followed by 'some whitespace' (PCRE: `\s`) or use a look around pattern `(?![A-Z0-9])` - for 'not followed by this.

And for 3 - non-whitespace may be what you want - `\S` in PCRE definitions.

```
/(?<!\w)#[A-Z]\S{1,49}(?!\w)/i
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB4zV0/2)

Edit: Given this may be javascript specific, and you can't use lookbehind, then the above may not work for you. If you are tying our regex query to a particular language, it is useful to specify that constraint in the question.

Comment: 'twould be useful to tag a specific language in the original question in that case.