# Make All hashtags clickable in Template with Templatetags

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to turn every hashtag in the `comment` textfield to url so that it will be clickable.

For example, a user submit,

```
s = "I can't get enough of #SO because #developers are very #supportive"
```

I want it to return like this in template,

```
I can't get enough of #SO because #developers are very #supportive
```

Where whole text will display and all hashtag will be clickable by embedding {hashtag}.

I tried the below templatetags code but it won't return the hashtags with the text. It will only return this,

```
<a href='http://example.com/tags/SO'>SO</a>
```

app_extras.py

```
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='hashchange')
def hashchange(value):
    vx=re.findall(r"#(\w+)", value)
    for n in vx:
        pm="<a href='http://example.com/tags/{0}'>{0}</a>".format(n)
        return pm
```

In the template, I did,

```
{{object.comment|safe|hashchange}}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There is probably some JS library that is meant to do this.

Comment: can yu recommend a library for me?

Comment: Some regex in JS could also do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655333/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-replace-hash-tags-with-links-from-a-jquery-data-attri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) to mark your return value as html.  Keep in mind that since you are marking it as safe, you must [escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape) it first.  [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is what you were looking for:

```
import re
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

def create_hashtag_link(tag):
    url = "/tags/{}/".format(tag)
    # or: url = reverse("hashtag", args=(tag,))
    return '<a href="{}">#{}</a>'.format(url, tag)


@register.filter()
def hashtag_links(value):
    return mark_safe(
        re.sub(r"#(\w+)", lambda m: create_hashtag_link(m.group(1)),
               escape(value)))
```

Note:  We assume that `value` is text (unescaped), and `create_hashtag_link(tag)` assumes `tag` is a word (`\w+`) and does not need escaping.  For creating links to other fragments of text, use [`format_html()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) instead of `.format()`

Comment: I suggest using `conditional_escape` instead of `escape` to avoid double-escaping

Comment: Thanks Udi. You rock!

Comment: @DanielHepper : If it is already html, stuff like `<a href="#abc">` can already be present, and would require to parse the input value.  Let's keep the input value text and the solution simple...