# Django - hashtag links on all templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, chat

I want to have whenever someone writes "#id_of_model" automatically the link to the model. 
The idea behind is I have a chat where people are discussing stuff and to make communication easier, I would like to provide more user friendly links.

My first idea was that I would check every sent message - which is stored in an model - if it contains a #id_of_model, then convert it to an link and finally save it.

Does anyone know an easier solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am probably missing something, but maybe this can help.

If you have a urls.py like:

```
url(r'^message/link/(?P<message_uuid>[\w]+)', views.message, name='message'),
```

and that could have multiple variables passed in the url, then your views.py could do something like:

```
def message(request, message_uuid=False):
    if message_uuid:
        # Create the link in the data model
```

Another approach could be to swap the # for a ? and pass the variable in GET request, like ?id=2:

```
def message(request):
    message_id = request.GET.get(id, False)
    if message_id:
        #Create the link in the data model
```

I know it isn't exactly what you asked for, but hope that it helps.

Comment: That was kinda my idea but if I create an HTML-Link in my text I would have to display it like this {{ message.text | safe }} which would allow users to use html & css in their messages which I don't want. 

Or is there something I am missing out?

Comment: just came across this one: https://github.com/semente/django-hashtags

I will check it out and let you know how it went, looks exactly like what I need!

Comment: This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137455/make-all-hashtags-clickable-in-template-with-templatetags