# JS replace every #word to <div>#word</div> in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, replace

I'm creating socket based chat app. I would like to change my incoming messages: when an word in an message contains # it has to be surrounded by div tags. For example `'this is #an message'` has to be converted to `'this is <div>#an</div> message'`. I'm using jQuery.

Comment: this is **_a_** message. Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575041/change-hash-tag-to-link-on-page-load

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with *RegEX* like this:

```js
var content="this is #an message";
alert(content.replace(/(#\S+)/gi,"<div>$1</div>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via regular expressions and javascript string methods. Check out this post, it should supply everything you need. 
[How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/2202290)