# Find all text nodes in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729983/highlight-word-in-html-text-but-not-markup/10730063#10730063) I needed to find all text nodes under a particular node. I *can* do this like so:

```
function textNodesUnder(root){
  var textNodes = [];
  addTextNodes(root);
  [].forEach.call(root.querySelectorAll('*'),addTextNodes);
  return textNodes;

  function addTextNodes(el){
    textNodes = textNodes.concat(
      [].filter.call(el.childNodes,function(k){
        return k.nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

However, this seems inelegant in light of the fact that with XPath one could simply query for `.//text()` and be done with it.

**What's the simplest way to get all text nodes under a particular element in an HTML document, that works on IE9+, Safari5+, Chrome19+, Firefox12+, Opera11+?**

*"Simplest" is defined loosely as "efficient and short, without golfing".*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes

Comment: Aw, bugger. Thanks, Jack, I did search but failed to find that question.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it didn't show up in the side bar either, but I found it while doing a Google search :)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Using [`createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker) is a very efficient way of querying multiple nodes from the DOM.

```js
/**
 * Retrieves an array of all text nodes under a given element.
 *
 * @param { Node } el - The element under which to search for text nodes.
 * @returns { Node[] } An array of text nodes found under the given element.
 */
function textNodesUnder(el) {
  const children = [] // Type: Node[]
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT)
  while(walker.nextNode()) {
    children.push(walker.currentNode)
  }
  return children
}
```

Note: A much more complete answer with multiple examples can be found here: [getElementsByTagName() equivalent for textNodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes)

Comment: @julmot On my computer, looking for all text nodes on this page using Chrome v50, it takes 1900μs using the first technique, but 220μs using the TreeWalker technique. So, 8 or 9 times faster.

Comment: I had to tweek this in order to exclude the contents of `<script>` elements: https://gist.github.com/Daniel-Hug/1415b4d027e3e9854456f4e812ea2ce1

Comment: If you're using the TreeWalker method and you want to exclude script or style tags as Web_Designer mentioned, you can pass a filter as the third argument to createTreeWalker

Comment: @VinayPai - Caveat: the `filter` is only run on [`a node that has passed the whatToShow check`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker#Parameters), so in this case you couldn't use the convenient `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT`, but instead you'd have to add additional logic to manually filter text nodes by `nodeType` or something.

Comment: @Web_Designer - Alternative while still using `document.createTreeWalker()`: https://gist.github.com/Sphinxxxx/ed372d176c5c2c1fd9ea1d8d6801989b

Comment: If anyone is confused why there are four arguments: https://genius.engineering/psa-internet-explorer-requires-all-four-arguments-to-documentcreatetreewalker/

Comment: @Sphinxxx the filter acts as a post-processsor, so it takes into account the second argument, i.e., if you pass `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` as the second argument then the filter would further filter those text nodes.

Answer (score 6):

```
function deepText(node){
    var A= [];
    if(node){
        node= node.firstChild;
        while(node!= null){
            if(node.nodeType== 3) A[A.length]=node;
            else A= A.concat(deepText(node));
            node= node.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: How about `while (node)` without the `!= null`?

Comment: Or even `for (node=node.firstChild;node;node=node.nextSibling){ … }`

Comment: I was worried that the recursive solution might run into stack limit issues, but [I see now that this is unlikely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826992/browser-javascript-stack-size-limit).

Comment: Once you know the first (parent) node is a child node the only possible values for node.nextSibling are another child node or null.