# How do I retrieve contents of tag when it has no name?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following in HTML code:

```
<div id="arM">
<metryczka>[ DGW RP ] - Gazeta Wyborcza nr
<numergazety>280</numergazety>, wydanie <mutacja></mutacja>
z dnia 02/12/2013<dzial>Ukraina się burzy</dzial>, str.
<strona>2</strona>
</metryczka>
</div>
```

To retrieve the contents of `<metryczka>` I use:

```
document.getElementById("arM").getElementsByTagName("metryczka")[0].InnerText
```

And I get:

```
[ DGW RP ] - Gazeta Wyborcza nr
<numergazety>280</numergazety>, wydanie <mutacja></mutacja>
z dnia 02/12/2013<dzial>Ukraina się burzy</dzial>, str.
<strona>2</strona>
```

But how do I get e.g. everything between `</mutacja>` and `<dzial>` (that is `z dnia 02/12/2013`) or `[ DGW RP ] - Gazeta Wyborcza nr`? I have heard of `document.querySelector` but I don't know if it is applicable here.

Comment: you are looking for text nodes

jQuery:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery

no jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730309/find-all-text-nodes-in-html-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `textNode` by using **[`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)**, **[`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling)** or **[`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)** based on the tag

For example :

```js
console.log(
  document.getElementById("arM").getElementsByTagName("mutacja")[0].nextSibling.textContent, //  using nextSibling
  document.getElementById("arM").getElementsByTagName('metryczka')[0].childNodes[0].textContent, // using childNodes
  document.getElementById("arM").getElementsByTagName('numergazety')[0].previousSibling.textContent // using previousSibling
)
```

```html
<div id="arM">
  <metryczka>[ DGW RP ] - Gazeta Wyborcza nr
    <numergazety>280</numergazety>, wydanie
    <mutacja></mutacja>
    z dnia 02/12/2013
    <dzial>Ukraina się burzy</dzial>, str.
    <strona>2</strona>
  </metryczka>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not the expected output

Comment: @Reddy : `how do I get e.g. everything between </mutacja> and <dzial> (that is z dnia 02/12/2013) or [ DGW RP ] - Gazeta Wyborcza nr`

Comment: Yes thats right, But your output is not as mentioned ... you have a extra `280, wydanie ` and also `Ukraina się burzy, str. 2`

Comment: @Reddy : check the console... for me it's shows  `z dnia 02/12/2013
     [ DGW RP ] - Gazeta Wyborcza nr`

Comment: yes I thought the stuff on screen was the output, I added `http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js` to show console output on the snippet..

Comment: Upvoted and accepted. Much appreciated. This answer gives the expected result. In `AutoHotKey` (a language used to automate Windows tasks) all of the snippets work but one – `childNodes[0].textContent`. I think `childNodes` fails to work in this language. It doesn't change the fact the answer is perfect. Many thanks.

Comment: @menteith : glad to help you :)