# Is there anyway to apply letter and word spacing to a "font" using css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a custom font with code like this -

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'classylight';
url : 'some path';
font-weight:normal;
    }
```

I want to set some values **exclusively** for this font everywhere on the site like letter spacing, word spacing, and other styles. I wanted to reduce unneccessary process, and looked for `attribute=style` property.

I tried -

```
body [style="font-family:classylight"] {
letter-spacing:50px;
word-spacing:-20px; 
}
```

It's not working. Can anyone help? I would like to use only css for this. If there's no possibility in css, please refer with javascript, jquery.

PS - I'm not looking for answers which adds styles directly to body part like

```
p {
font-family: classylight;
letter-spacing:50px;
word-spacing:-20px; 
    }
```

Comment: You really should read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Comment: But i never used the code like this.

Comment: '.className {
  @font-face {
    font-family: MyHelvetica;
    src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold"),
         local("HelveticaNeue-Bold"),
         url(MgOpenModernaBold.ttf);
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}'

Comment: Nobody has used such a code, `body [font-family='classylight']` selects elements from the body which have `font-family` attribute set to `classylight`, very likely that selector doesn't find any elements.

Comment: 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp'

Comment: No, In body part I have values set with the particular font name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unike text color and size, You can't change letter spacing and word spacing using `attribute=style` property. You should either change them  while creating by changing pen width or you should change them in body of css.

Answer (score 0):

Use **rem** and **em** for all the letter spacing, word spacing, etc.
And for the font-weight, it is because the initial declaration is overwriting your own font-weight.

Comment: How could changing units make css work? Sorry to say but you answered this question just for answering.

Comment: Because rem is based on the root font size which has a default value. And Em is based on the parent font size. These two are better options especially for letter spacing etc since you have custom font declaration.

Comment: These units are not for font sizing!

Comment: [https://css-tricks.com/confused-rem-em/]

Answer (score 0):

you might find this useful i guess.. this are the common most use css text property

```html
<h1 style="

text-align: center; 
font-size: 25px;  
color:#FF0000;      
font-family: Arial Black,Arial,Helvetica,Verdana,Trebuchet MS,Comic Sans MS,sans-serif;    
font-style: normal;   
font-weight: 1000;
background-color: #D3D3D3; 
line-height: 3;

">TEST 123</h1>
```

also about your question "font-weight:bold" not working perhaps it being overwritten by other value such as < h1 > which make text already huge...

Comment: Thanks for the effort mam. But i'm trying to **exclusively** apply the styles to the font

Answer (score 0):

So you can't really use `letter-spacing` in font declarations. What you could do however, is create a `class` which has the letter spacing you want, and then add the class to the HTML element. Like so:

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   url : 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400&display=swap';
   font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   url : 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap';
   font-weight: normal;
}
        
.roboto-norm{
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   font-weight: normal;
}
        
.roboto-norm-ltr-spc{
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   font-weight: normal;
   letter-spacing: 0.25em !important;
}
        
.opensans-norm{
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   font-weight: normal;
}
        
.opensans-norm-ltr-spc{
   font-family: 'Open Sans';
   font-weight: normal;
   letter-spacing: 0.25em !important;
}
```

```html
<label class="roboto-norm">Normal roboto letter spacing</label>
<br><br>
<label class="roboto-norm-ltr-spc">Custom roboto letter spacing</label>

<br><br>
<br><br>

<label class="opensans-norm">Normal open sans letter spacing</label>
<br><br>
<label class="opensans-norm-ltr-spc">Custom open sans letter spacing</label>
```

As for the `font-weight: normal` part, what you're doing with the `@font-face` rule is that you're declaring the font. It's basically a variable of sorts, which you'd then be referencing when styling the HTML elements. The weight of the font is part of that.

The snippet below should make it clearer. What I've done is that I've imported 2 styles of the `Roboto` font, the first being of regular weight, aka `400`, and the other of bold weight, aka `700`.

```css
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   url : 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400&display=swap';
   font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Roboto';
   url : 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap';
   font-weight: bold;
}
    
*{
   font-family: 'Roboto';
}
    
#normal{
   font-weight: normal;
}
#bold{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label id="normal">normal font</label>
<br><br>
<label id="bold">bold font</label>
```

Comment: Yeah. Got the answer for second part. But, This is not the one i'm searching for first part. I want everything within the body with that specific font family to have a specified letter and word spacing.

Comment: And the first part of the answer gives you a solution for that. Create a class to suit your requirements by adding the specific font family and what not, and use it. What you want cannot be done because there is no selector that can be used to select all elements of a certain font family.

Comment: No bro. What i'm saying is possible. I did a error and want to know where i have done that mistake. CSS Attribute property is especially used for this. I use different types of fonts and each one of them requires different styles. So, I'm trying to adopt especially this method.

Comment: After your edit to the answer, I understood what you are trying to say. I way before posting this question did that. It works perfectly. What i'm trying to ask is - Is there any way in css, by using attributes, to directly declare the font styles like i was trying so that the redundancy would be decreased.

Comment: You cannot, because there is no selector for 'font-family'. You can through JS/jQuery, but that would require looping through all the elements, and this is much more expensive than the CSS alternative, which is to use classes.

Comment: No bro. Js is not as expensive as you think and i already saw a similar answer to my question on stack overflow itself. but im unable to find it again.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The `font-feature-settings` property allows control over advanced typographic features in OpenType fonts. These settings solved in my case:

```
body{
  font-variant: none;
  font-feature-settings: "c2sc", "smcp";
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

Answer (score 0):

### JS approach: get all text nodes and apply classes

1. We're first selecting all text nodes.
2. Then we loop through them and check their parent element's computed style properties via `getComputedStyle(textNode.parentNode)`
3. define css class rules

```js
let textNodes = textNodesInEl(document.body) 

// add font-family classes
textNodes.forEach(text=>{
  let el = text.parentNode;
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
  let fontFamily = style.getPropertyValue('font-family');
  let fontStyle = style.getPropertyValue('font-style');
  let fontWeight = style.getPropertyValue('font-weight');
  let className = 'font__'+fontFamily.replaceAll(' ', '_').toLowerCase()+'__'+fontStyle;
  let classNameFontWeight = 'fontweight__'+fontWeight;
  el.classList.add(className);  
  el.classList.add(classNameFontWeight);  
})


/**
 * Get text nodes in element
 * based on:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730309/find-all-text-nodes-in-html-page#10730777
 */
function textNodesInEl(node) {
    let textNodes = [];
    for (node = node.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            textNodes.push(node);
        }
        else {
            textNodes = textNodes.concat(textNodesInEl(node));
        }
    }
    // filter empty text nodes
    textNodes = textNodes.filter(node => node.textContent.trim())
    return textNodes;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-weight: 700;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.fontweight__700{
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.font__verdana__normal{
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  color:red
}

.font__verdana__italic{
  letter-spacing: -0.05em;
  color: green
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading 1</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span style="font-family:verdana">consectetuer </span> adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. <em style="font-family:verdana">Nulla consequat massa quis</em> enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</p>

<h2>Heading 2</h2>

<p>Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante.</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td>Col 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col 1</td>
    <td>Col 2</td>
    <td><span style="font-family:verdana;">Col 3</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could also add other property values like `font-style` or `font-weight` for more specific filtering.