# How to highlight only a certain part of text content in any element tag using js?

Tags: javascript

```
<p>Non-highlighted part. Only this part must be highlighted. Non-highlighted part.</p>
```

How do I highlight only "Only this part must be highlighted." part out of the complete text content of the `<p>` tag?

I was trying to search for a text and then highlight it using the following code.

```
var xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Only this part must be highlighted.')]";
var matchingElements = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

const numberOfElements = matchingElements.snapshotLength;

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    const element = matchingElements.snapshotItem(i);

    // Do something with each element:
    console.log(element.tagName, element.textContent);

    // Example: Highlight the element
    element.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

This code highlights the complete element where the text is found. In this case, the complete `<p>` tag will be highlighted. How do I highlight only the text found?

Comment: Why not wrap the text you want to highlight with a `span` tag so you can manipulate it's css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your original code only works with text nodes, here is an implementation that finds all text nodes (*using a treeWalker*), then filters those that match the text you want to find and finally creates a range of that text and wraps it with a `span` element and adds a class to it.

I have added a utility method to remove all highlights as well.

The code to select the text nodes using a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) is taken from [Find all text nodes in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10730309/find-all-text-nodes-in-html-page) so credits belong to @Phrogz for that.

```js
function highlightContent(textToHighlight) {
  const allTextNodes = textNodesUnder(document.body);
  var matchingElements = allTextNodes.filter(textNode => textNode.textContent.includes(textToHighlight));


  for (let textNode of matchingElements) {
    const textOffset = textNode.textContent.indexOf(textToHighlight);

    const range = new Range();
    range.setStart(textNode, textOffset);
    range.setEnd(textNode, textOffset + textToHighlight.length);
    
    const wrapper = document.createElement('span');
    wrapper.classList.add('highlighted');
    range.surroundContents(wrapper);
  }

}

function unHighlightContent() {
  const highlights = document.querySelectorAll('.highlighted');

  console.log([...highlights].map(n => n.parentNode));
  for (let highlight of highlights) {
    highlight.replaceWith(highlight.childNodes[0]);
  }
}

highlightContent('Only this part must be highlighted.');
//unHighlightContent();



function textNodesUnder(el) {
  const children = [] // Type: Node[]
  const walker = document.createTreeWalker(el, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, (node) => node.parentNode.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT')
  while (walker.nextNode()) {
    children.push(walker.currentNode)
  }
  return children
}
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>Non-highlighted part. Only this part must be highlighted. Non-highlighted part.</p>

<p>Non-highlighted part. Only this part must be highlighted. Non-highlighted part.</p>

<p>Non-highlighted part. Only this part must be highlighted. Non-highlighted part.</p>

<p>Non-highlighted part. Only this part must be highlighted. Non-highlighted part.</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this. your can select the element and search and wrap the span around your required highlighted text.

```js
const elem = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
const textToSearch = "Only this part must be highlighted"
elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent.replace(textToSearch, `<span class="highlight">${textToSearch}</span>`);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Non-highlighted part. Only this part must be highlighted. Non-highlighted part.</p>
```