# Access return value from a Javascript in JavaFX

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, webengine

I have the following Javascript executed in a webengine.
Source: [Execute a Javascript function for a WebView from a JavaFX program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029964/execute-a-javascript-function-for-a-webview-from-a-javafx-program/39722454#39722454)

This Javascript highlights a specific word on a website.

```
WebView webView = new WebView();
final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
engine.load("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029964/execute-a-javascript-function-for-a-webview-from-a-javafx-program");

engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            engine.executeScript(
                "function highlightWord(root,word){"
                + "  textNodesUnder(root).forEach(highlightWords);"
                + ""
                + "  function textNodesUnder(root){"
                + "    var n,a=[],w=document.createTreeWalker(root,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);"
                + "    while(n=w.nextNode()) a.push(n);"
                + "    return a;"
                + "  }"
                + ""
                + "  function highlightWords(n){"
                + "    for (var i; (i=n.nodeValue.indexOf(word,i)) > -1; n=after){"
                + "      var after = n.splitText(i+word.length);"
                + "      var highlighted = n.splitText(i);"
                + "      var span = document.createElement('span');"
                + "      span.style.backgroundColor='#f00';"
                + "      span.appendChild(highlighted);"
                + "      after.parentNode.insertBefore(span,after);"
                + "    }"
                + "  }"
                + "}"
                + "\n"
                + "highlightWord(document.body,'function');");
        }
    }
});
```

I want to check, whether a website contains a specific word and I thought this code is a good starting point, since it worked fine and highlights words.
What I need now is, that the Javascript should count when highlighting.
Then, if a word is contained (counter >= 1), I want to get a boolean return value, that I can access in JavaFX.

I tried some things but I really dont know how to midify the Script to add a counter and a return value that can be accessed outside the script.

Thank you all for reading.

Answer (score 0):

When using [`executeScript`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript%28java.lang.String%29) the evaluation result is returned based on the rules written in the javadoc of the method. Also the [javadoc of `WebEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) informs you about this possibility.

> execution result, converted to a Java object using the following
>   rules:
>
> - JavaScript Int32 is converted to java.lang.Integer
> - Other JavaScript numbers to java.lang.Double
> - JavaScript string to java.lang.String
> - JavaScript boolean to java.lang.Boolean
> - JavaScript null to null
> - Most JavaScript objects get wrapped as netscape.javascript.JSObject
> - JavaScript JSNode objects get mapped to instances of netscape.javascript.JSObject, that also implement org.w3c.dom.Node
> - A special case is the JavaScript class JavaRuntimeObject which is used to wrap a Java object as a JavaScript value - in this case we
>     just extract the original Java value.

So, if the javascript script returns an Int32, you can get it like:

```
Integer executeScript = (Integer) engine.executeScript(...);
```

Your updated example (for example):

```
Integer numOfHighlights = (Integer) engine.executeScript(
    "function highlightWord(root,word){"
    + "  count = 0;"
    + "  textNodesUnder(root).forEach(highlightWords);"
    + ""
    + "  function textNodesUnder(root){"
    + "    var n,a=[],w=document.createTreeWalker(root,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false);"
    + "    while(n=w.nextNode()) a.push(n);"
    + "    return a;"
    + "  }"
    + ""
    + "  function highlightWords(n){"
    + "    for (var i; (i=n.nodeValue.indexOf(word,i)) > -1; n=after){"
    + "      var after = n.splitText(i+word.length);"
    + "      var highlighted = n.splitText(i);"
    + "      var span = document.createElement('span');"
    + "      span.style.backgroundColor='#f00';"
    + "      span.appendChild(highlighted);"
    + "      after.parentNode.insertBefore(span,after);"
    + "      count = count + 1;"
    + "    }"
    + "  }"
    + "  return count;"
    + "}"
    + "\n"
    + "highlightWord(document.body,'execute');");

System.out.println("Number of highlights are: " + numOfHighlights);
```

*Outputs*

```
Number of highlights are: 9
```

I have only added a counter variable that is incremented for every highlighted item and then finally this variables is returned.