# Can a Chrome Extension with Manifest V3 modify tabs in the background?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, background, service-worker

I am trying to get into chrome extension development and want to make an extension which highlights a specific word on every page from a background script.
If I give my extension the activeTab permission, it is listed as "Access requested" and I need to invoke it by opening the popup, then after reloading the page it will highlight the word.

[image: Access requested]

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/activeTab/) says "essentially, *activeTab* grants the *tabs* permission temporarily", so I switched to giving the tabs permission because I don't want to open the popup every time I visit a new website. However, now the extension is listed as "no access needed" and the highlighting does not work regardless of whether I invoke the popup or not.

[image: No access needed]

Here is my service-worker background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {  
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      function: highlightwords,
    });
  }
})


function highlightwords(){
  var list = document.getElementsByTagName("p")
  var search_words = ["the", "it", "you"]
  var words = []

  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    var words = list[i].textContent.split(' ')
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
      if (search_words.includes(words[j])) {
        console.log(words[j]);
        var elem = document.createElement("span")
        elem.textContent = words[j]
        elem.style.color = "red"
        words[j]=elem.outerHTML
      }      
    }
    
    list[i].innerHTML = words.join(' ')
  }
}
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "/images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "permissions": ["storage", "scripting", "tabs"]
}
```

I'd be very grateful for any hint on what's going wrong here or which alternatives there are (apart from using manifest v2, which probably doesn't have much of a future, at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only purpose of the `tabs` permission is to show `url` in `changeInfo` and `tab` objects e.g. in chrome.tabs.onUpdated event. You don't use it and you don't need it for this task.

1. Remove `tabs` and `scripting` permissions, remove the background worker.
2. Declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in manifest.json

   ```json
   "content_scripts": [{
     "matches": ["*://*/*"],
     "js": ["content.js"]
   }]
   ```
3. content.js will run in all http/https sites (this is what the first `*` in `*://*/*` means) and highlight the text.

P.S. Note that your current code destroys event listeners added by the page to any nested elements inside `p` because you assign to `innerHTML`. This is bad. A much better approach is to replace the matching parts of text inline by using DOM methods createTreeWalker and splitText, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730063), or just use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/).