# Set multiple values to variable and use that variable in DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to replace some words in DOM with chrome extension.
While the hard coded word works and is replaced, I don't know how to do it dynamically, e.g. to loop through several words and if any of them is on web page, it should be used as a variable and replaced on page.
Since I'm a n00b (obviously), I hope I'm making sense.

Here's the code:

```
const Key = ('covid-19', 'coronavirus', 'covid'); // TODO: use this as a variable in innerhtml below

const words = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, td, caption, span');

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'tag';
let text = document.createTextNode('TAG');

for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(words[i].innerHTML.includes('COVID-19')|| words[i].innerHTML.includes('COVID-19')){
       words[i].innerHTML = words[i].innerHTML.replace('COVID-19', '<a href="https://www.cdc.gov/">ALERT</a>');
       div.appendChild(text);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [Javascript .replace command replace page text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7275856) and [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15604140)

Comment: Thanks, I looked into those, but it seems it's not working when trying to replace words with links.

Comment: You would need another example: [Highlight word in HTML text (but not markup)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10730063) BTW all of this should be possible by using `mark.js` library.

Comment: not a clue on how to convert the highlightning code into my own purpose, so I'll give it a pass, sorry:) I've searched everywhere on SO for my solution, but no luck. It would be great to have just a func to do as I need, nothing complicated.