# How to find phone numbers inside of a document

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out a way to parse a document for phone numbers (in several formats) so that it automatically wraps them in a span. Here's the code I threw together.

```
findPhones = function(){
  var pNumber = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;  
  var findPhone = $('*:contains('+pNumber+')');
    findPhone.each(function(i) {
      $(this).prepend('<span>');
        alert('Phone Number Found, delete me');
      $(this).append('</span>');          
    });
}
```

I have no idea how to check the entire document (or element for that matter) to see if it's a phone number.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhrXz/)

Comment: use `.wrap` not prepend/append http://api.jquery.com/wrap/  `$(this).wrap('<span />');`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to search all text nodes. An easy (and potentially awful) way to do this is by using `document.body.innerHTML`, but this can lead to severe disruption of other JavaScript that is bound to particular DOM elements. I recommend you use a `NodeIterator` or `TreeWalker` to do it, so that you can treat text nodes individually without disrupting the DOM. [Here's an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275650/javascript-replace-command-replace-page-text/7275856#7275856) that you might find useful *(disclaimer: I wrote that answer)*.