# Replacing Text with Treewalker in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I found the example below of how to replace text with Treewalker here: [Javascript .replace command replace page text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275650/javascript-replace-command-replace-page-text)

```
// create a TreeWalker of all text nodes
var allTextNodes = document.createTreeWalker(document.body,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT),
// some temp references for performance
tmptxt,
tmpnode,
// compile the RE and cache the replace string, for performance
cakeRE = /cake/g
replaceValue = "pie";

// iterate through all text nodes
while (allTextNodes.nextNode()) {
tmpnode = allTextNodes.currentNode;
tmptxt = tmpnode.nodeValue;
tmpnode.nodeValue = tmptxt.replace(cakeRE,replaceValue);
}
```

Would it be possible to modify this so it can check for and replace multiple words as well as not being case sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a pattern to be case-insensitive, you can use the `i` flag. [**[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags)**]

If you want to replace multiple words with the one specific word, then just modify the regex pattern like this:

```
cakeRE = /word1|word2|.../gi;
```

If you want to replace each word with a different replacement value, you could create a set of corresponding pattern-replacement pairs and iterate over it. E.g.:

```
...
patterns = [/cake/gi, /muffin/gi, /pancake/gi];
replacements = ["pie", "brownie", "cheese-cake"];
...
tmpnode = allTextNodes.currentNode;
patterns.forEach(function(pattern, idx) {
    tmpnode.nodeValue = tmpnode.nodeValue.replace(pattern, replacements[idx]);
});
...
```

Alternatively, you could also use the `replace` variation with a function as its 2nd param. [**[more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)**]

```
...
replDict = {
    "cake": "pie",
    "muffin": "brownie",
    "pancake": "cheese-cake"
};
pattern = new RegExp(Object.keys(replDict).join("|"), "gi");
...
tmpnode = allTextNodes.currentNode;
tmpnode.nodeValue = tmpnode.nodeValue.replace(pattern, function(match) {
    return replDict[match];
});
...
```

Comment: I used the second method and it worked, but some instances of "cake" get replaced with undefined. For example if go to Wikipedia, the first word which is "cake" in bold is "undefined". Is there a way to fix this problem?