# How to change all texts in DOM without breaking existing HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, userscripts

I want to replace specific texts on a page with javascript. For simplicty lets say I want to replace all letters **A** with the letter **X**. Important is that it's not going to break inline HTML.

Is there a simple way to iterate over all DOM elements and only change actual texts?

```
<span>hello world <a href="/">abcd</a>..</span>
```

should become

```
<span>hello world <a href="/">xbcd</a>..</span>
```

and not

```
<spxn>hello world <x href="/">xbcd</x>..</spxn>
```

Comment: Assign all the spans the same class id then use JQuery to change the text of all elements with that class name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript .replace command replace page text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275650/javascript-replace-command-replace-page-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over [all text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes), and change their `nodeValue` if they contain an `a`:

```js
function getAllTextNodes() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body, 
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
}

getAllTextNodes().forEach((node) => {
  const { nodeValue } = node;
  const newValue = nodeValue.replace(/a/g, 'x');
  if (newValue !== nodeValue) {
    node.nodeValue = newValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="/">abcd</a>
```

You can also create a whitelist or blacklist of parents whose text nodes are changeable, if you want:

```js
function getAllTextNodes() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body, 
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
}

const tagNamesToKeepUnchanged = ['SCRIPT'];

getAllTextNodes().forEach((node) => {
  if (tagNamesToKeepUnchanged.includes(node.parentNode.tagName)) {
    return;
  }
  const { nodeValue } = node;
  const newValue = nodeValue.replace(/a/g, 'x');
  if (newValue !== nodeValue) {
    node.nodeValue = newValue;
  }
});

const obj = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector('script[type="application/json"]').textContent
);
console.log(obj.key);
```

```html
<a href="/">abcd</a>
<p>foo bar</p>
<script type="application/json">{"key":"value"}</script>
```

This will preserve tag names, event listeners, and pretty much everything except the content of certain text nodes.

Comment: This changes the content of <script> blocks

Comment: Oh, that's true, though luckily it probably doesn't matter since the scripts will have already been executed. You can make a whitelist of parent elements whose text is changeable (or a blacklist) if you want

Comment: It doesn't matter because scripts runs just once when they were added, and it's really trivial to check if for some reason someone wants that.

Comment: This is cool answer, I didn't know about `createTreeWalker`! +1

Comment: it actually matters. it manipulates functions within script blocks which gets me exceptions later on.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this:

```
/**
 * Executes operation over all text nodes in a document
 * @param {HTMLElement} element
 * @param {function(Text):void} callback
 */
function processTextNodes(element, callback) {
    // For text node, execute callback
    if (element.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        callback(element);
    // Otherwise, loop over child nodes
    else if (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (const childNode of element.childNodes) {
            if (childNode.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
                callback(childNode);
            // Recursion to child nodes
            else {
                processTextNodes(childNode, callback);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example try this:

```
processTextNodes(document.body, (el)=>{el.data = el.data.toUpperCase()})
```

I used this in several userscripts that replace words in news articles to make them more fun.

Answer (score 0):

The crawler by @CertainPerformance made JSfiddle.net crash for me.
I also need to replace the text node with an html element, so I had to move away from text nodes and I settled for more modest solution with an extensive `regex lookaround` to ensure html tags, properties and values are (mostly) not edited.

```js
var list = ["crabe", "eau", "voir", "nom", "de", "des", "le", "les"];
var colorThoseWords = function(arr) {
  words = arr.join('|');
  // Regex lookareound: https://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html
  // Regex `negative lookbehind` and `negative lookahead`
  // Run it: https://regex101.com/r/NZ5LQZ/1
  var s = `(?<![<=#"'\`:;,./({[-])\\b(${words})\\b(?![>=#"'\`:)\]}-])`,
    r = new RegExp(s, 'gi');
  console.log({r});

  $("p,li,h2,h3,a").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(this).html(text.replace(r, "<i class='signit-colored'>$1</i>"));
  });
};
var uncolorWords = function() {
  $(".signit-colored").each(function() {
    var $text = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith($text);
  });
};
colorThoseWords(list);
// uncolorWords();
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/x7f24qnv/13/

I suspect @Tomáš_Zato_-_Reinstate_Monica's transverse solution may be best if we edit the `TEXT_NODE`'s parent.