# How would I use TreeWalker Method to replace multiple words

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

[Javascript .replace command replace page text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275650/javascript-replace-command-replace-page-text)

My apologies if this is not the best way to ask a question in reference to an answered question, but given the above solution, how would I go about replacing more than one word/phrase? Do I just duplicate these lines with additional ones?

```
    cakeRE = /cake/g,
    replaceValue = "pie";
```

```
    tmpnode.nodeValue = tmptxt.replace(cakeRE, replaceValue);
```

Comment: See [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15604140)

Comment: Do you mind posting this as the answer so I can mark it answered and upvote you? :) Thank you so much!

Comment: In such cases the question is duplicated/deleted, I think.